# Custom source in flume

Tags: flume

I have created a custom source for flume and copied the jar files in the following locations :

```
 mkdir -p /usr/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/MyFlumeSource/lib/MyFlumeSource.jar

 chown -R flume:flume /var/lib/flume-ng/
```

Also in /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume-env.sh

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/MyFlumeSource/lib/MyFlumeSource.jar"
```

Updated the Flume configuration file as

```
 # Name the components on this agent 
tail1.sources = seq-source  
tail1.channels = mem-channel
tail1.sinks = hdfs-sink

# Describe/configure Source
tail1.sources.seq-source.type = org.custom.flume.source.MySource

# Describe the sink
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = /user/flume
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.filePrefix = log
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Use a channel which buffers events in file
tail1.channels.mem-channel.type = memory
tail1.channels.mem-channel.capacity = 1000
tail1.channels.mem-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
tail1.sources.seq-source.channels = mem-channel
tail1.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = mem-channel
```

Trying to run the flume agent as

```
flume-ng agent  --conf /var/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/MyFlumeSource/lib/MyFlumeSource.jar --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume-conf.properties --name tail1

flume-ng agent --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume-conf.properties --name tail1
```

In both cases I am getting the following error :

```
 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to create source: seq-source, type: org.custom.flume.source.MySource, class: org.custom.flume.source.MySource
        at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:48)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:322)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:97)
        at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
        at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:44)
        ... 10 more
```

If any one aware of it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the plugin under `/usr/lib/flume-ng` but you are trying to run it from `/var/lib/flume-ng` and `/etc/flume-ng`.

In addition, it must be said that `--conf` option should be pointing to the entire configuration folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for flume Interceptor? You can add you class as Interceptors which processes message.
If Yes, you can do it in 2 simple steps.
1) Add your jar file to /lib
2)Add config in flume-conf.properties mentioning your Builder class name.